# SilverStripe 4.1 Email->addAttachment()?

Tags: silverstripe

I have a contact form that accepts a file input, I'd like to attach the file to the email that gets sent from the form.

Looking at the API reference isn't really helping, it states that the function expects a filepath with no clarification on anything beyond that.

The submit action will save a record of the into the database and this works correctly, something like:

```
$submission = MyDataObject::create();
$form->saveInto($submission);
$submission->write();
```

an Email object then gets created and sent. Both of these are functioning and working as expected.

Trying to attach the File I've tried:
`$email->addAttachemnt($submission->MyFile()->Link());`
which is the closest I can get to getting a filepath for the document. Dumping and pasting the resulting filepath being output by that call will download the form but that line throws an error and can't seem to locate the file.

I suspect that I'm misunderstanding what's supposed to be given to the function, clarification would be very much appreciated.

P.S. I don't currently have access to the code, I'm looking for some clarification on the function itself not an exact answer :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SilverStripe 4 the assets are abstracted away, so you can't guarantee that the file exists on your webserver. It generally will, but it could equally exist on a CDN somewhere for example.

When you handle files in SilverStripe 4 you should always use the *contents* of the file and whatever other metadata you have available, rather than relying on filesystem calls to load it.

This is how the silverstripe/userforms module attaches files to emails:

```
/** @var SilverStripe\Control\Email\Email $email */
$email->addAttachmentFromData(
    $file->getString(),   // stream of file contents
    $file->getFilename(), // original filename
    $file->getMimeType()  // mime type
);
```

Comment: Thanks, I came across this function but had no idea what it was actually looking for in those parameters. Worked a charm.

Answer (score 0):

I would try `$email->addAttachment($submission->MyFile()->Filename);` If it doesn't work, you may need to prepend `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` to the filename.

`$email->addAttachment($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $submission->MyFile()->Filename);`